# troubles with error: Divide by zero error encountered

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello two days I have tried to figure out why my code isn't working.
I am quite sure that it's a stupid mistake, but if anybody has time to check the code I would really appreciate.
I have tried to comment out this "SUM" case, but then everything else breaks

I know that this line screws with me, but I can't figure out how to fix this:

```
sum (Case when bm.CaseQTY IS NULL 
          then (k.postedqty / mm.CaseQTY)
          else (k.postedqty / bm.CaseQTY)
     End) as laoseiskaste,
sum (Case when bm.CaseQTY IS NULL
          then ((k.postedqty-k.reservordered-k.reservphysical-k.picked+k.registered) / mm.CaseQTY)
          else ((k.postedqty-k.reservordered-k.reservphysical-k.picked+k.registered) / bm.CaseQTY)
     End) as vabakaste
from (select s.itemid, i.product, i.ItemMiscRefId, i.MMFItemProductGroupId, s.INVENTDIMID,
   s.postedqty, s.registered, s.reservordered, s.reservphysical, s.picked, s.ordered,
   s.postedvalue, s.received, i.PrimaryVendorId, i.standardPalletQuantity
from inventsum s WITH (INDEX(I_174CLOSEDITEMDIMIDX),NOLOCK),
```

---

```
SELECT k.itemid AS itemid,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.mmfitemid, '') != '' THEN bm.mmfitemid ELSE mm.mmfitemid END) AS mmfitemid,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.itembarcode, '') != '' THEN bm.itembarcode ELSE mm.itembarcode END) AS itembarcode,
   e.name AS name, d.inventlocationid AS inventlocationid, d.inventbatchid AS inventbatchid,
   LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, ib.proddate, 121), 10) AS proddate,
   LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, ib.expdate, 121), 10) AS expdate,
   d.wmslocationid AS wmslocationid, d.wmspalletid AS wmspalletid, p.pallettypeid AS pallettypeid,
   xz.inputblockingcauseid AS inputblockingcauseid,  xz.outputblockingcauseid AS outputblockingcauseid,
   d.inventserialid AS inventserialid, d.inventownerid_via AS inventownerid_via,
   d.inventlabelid_via AS inventlabelid_via, d.inventtaxstampid AS inventtaxstampid,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.CaseQTY, 0) != 0 THEN bm.CaseQTY ELSE mm.CaseQTY END) AS caseqty,
   k.standardPalletQuantity AS palletqty,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.caseheight, 0) != 0 THEN bm.caseheight ELSE mm.caseheight END) AS caseheight,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casewidth, 0) != 0 THEN bm.casewidth ELSE mm.casewidth END) AS casewidth,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casedepth, 0) != 0 THEN bm.casedepth ELSE mm.casedepth END) AS casedepth,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casebarcode, '') != '' THEN bm.casebarcode ELSE mm.casebarcode END) AS casebarcode,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casebrutoweight, 0) != 0 THEN bm.casebrutoweight ELSE mm.casebrutoweight END) AS casebrutoweight,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.alcopct, 0) != 0 THEN bm.alcopct ELSE mm.alcopct END) AS alcopct,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.blockqty, 0) != 0 THEN bm.blockqty ELSE mm.blockqty END) AS blockqty,
   (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.exciseproductregnum, '') != ''
         THEN bm.exciseproductregnum
         ELSE mm.exciseproductregnum
    END) AS exciseproductregnum,
   SUM(k.postedqty + k.received + k.registered) AS postedqty,
   SUM(k.registered) AS registeredqty,
   SUM(k.reservordered + k.reservphysical) AS reservedqty, SUM(k.picked) AS pickedqty,
   SUM(k.postedqty - k.reservordered - k.reservphysical - k.picked + k.registered) AS freeqty,
   SUM(k.ordered) AS ordered, SUM(k.postedvalue) AS postedvalue,
   k.MMFItemProductGroupId AS mmfitemproductgroupid,
   SUM(CASE WHEN bm.CaseQTY IS NULL 
            THEN (k.postedqty / mm.CaseQTY)
            ELSE (k.postedqty / bm.CaseQTY)
       END) AS laoseiskaste,
   SUM(CASE WHEN bm.CaseQTY IS NULL
            THEN ((k.postedqty - k.reservordered - k.reservphysical - k.picked + k.registered) / mm.CaseQTY)
            ELSE ((k.postedqty - k.reservordered - k.reservphysical - k.picked + k.registered) / bm.CaseQTY)
       END) AS vabakaste
FROM (SELECT s.itemid, i.product, i.ItemMiscRefId, i.MMFItemProductGroupId, s.INVENTDIMID,
         s.postedqty, s.registered, s.reservordered, s.reservphysical, s.picked,
         s.ordered, s.postedvalue, s.received, i.PrimaryVendorId, i.standardPalletQuantity
      FROM inventsum s WITH (INDEX(I_174CLOSEDITEMDIMIDX), NOLOCK),
      inventtable i WITH (INDEX([I_175ITEMIDX]), NOLOCK)
      WHERE s.itemid = i.itemid
         AND s.DATAAREAID = @Var1
         AND i.DATAAREAID = @Var1
         AND s.PARTITION = 5637144576
         AND i.PARTITION = 5637144576
         AND RIGHT(s.ITEMID, 2) = 'LA'
         AND s.CLOSED = 0
         AND (s.POSTEDQTY != 0
              OR s.reservordered + s.reservphysical != 0
              OR s.ordered != 0
             )
) k
JOIN inventdim d WITH (INDEX(I_698DIMIDIDX), NOLOCK)
   ON (k.INVENTDIMID = d.INVENTDIMID
   AND d.DATAAREAID = @Var3
   AND d.PARTITION = 5637144576)
LEFT OUTER JOIN EcoresProductTranslation e WITH (INDEX(I_6869PRODUCTLANGUAGEIDX))
   ON (k.product = e.product
   AND e.languageid = 'et'
   AND e.PARTITION = 5637144576)
LEFT OUTER JOIN WMSPALLET p
   ON (p.WMSPALLETID = d.WMSPALLETID
   AND p.PARTITION = 5637144576
   AND p.DATAAREAID = @Var4)
LEFT OUTER JOIN InventItemMisc mm WITH (INDEX(I_103616RecId))
   ON (mm.RecId = k.ItemMiscRefId
   AND mm.PARTITION = 5637144576)
LEFT OUTER JOIN InventBatch ib WITH (INDEX(I_752itemBatchIdx))
   ON (ib.ItemId = k.ItemId
       AND ib.InventBatchId = d.InventBatchId
       AND ib.PARTITION = 5637144576
       AND ib.DATAAREAID = @Var5)
LEFT OUTER JOIN InventItemMisc bm WITH (INDEX(I_103616RecId))
   ON (bm.RecId = ib.ItemMiscRefId
       AND bm.PARTITION = 5637144576)
JOIN WMSLOCATIOn xz WITH (INDEX(/*I672COORDINATEDIDX*/ I_672LOCATIONIDX))
   ON (xz.inventlocationID = d.inventlocationID
       AND xz.wmslocationid = d.wmslocationid
       AND xz.partition = 5637144576
       AND xz.dataareaid = 'EWH')
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY k.itemid,
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.mmfitemid, '') != '' THEN bm.mmfitemid ELSE mm.mmfitemid END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.itembarcode, '') != '' THEN bm.itembarcode ELSE mm.itembarcode END),
    e.name, d.inventlocationid, d.inventbatchid, LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, ib.proddate, 121), 10),
    LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, ib.expdate, 121), 10), d.wmslocationid, d.wmspalletid,
    p.pallettypeid, xz.inputblockingcauseid, xz.outputblockingcauseid, d.inventserialid,
    d.inventownerid_via, d.inventlabelid_via, d.inventtaxstampid,
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.CaseQTY, 0) != 0 THEN bm.CaseQTY ELSE mm.CaseQTY END),
    k.standardPalletQuantity,
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.caseheight, 0) != 0 THEN bm.caseheight ELSE mm.caseheight END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casewidth, 0) != 0 THEN bm.casewidth ELSE mm.casewidth END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casedepth, 0) != 0 THEN bm.casedepth ELSE mm.casedepth END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casebarcode, '') != '' THEN bm.casebarcode ELSE mm.casebarcode END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casebrutoweight, 0) != 0 THEN bm.casebrutoweight ELSE mm.casebrutoweight END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.alcopct, 0) != 0 THEN bm.alcopct ELSE mm.alcopct END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.blockqty, 0) != 0 THEN bm.blockqty ELSE mm.blockqty END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.exciseproductregnum, '') != ''
          THEN bm.exciseproductregnum
          ELSE mm.exciseproductregnum
     END),
    k.MMFItemProductGroupId
ORDER BY k.itemid,
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.mmfitemid, '') != '' THEN bm.mmfitemid ELSE mm.mmfitemid END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.itembarcode, '') != '' THEN bm.itembarcode ELSE mm.itembarcode END),
    e.name, d.inventlocationid, d.inventbatchid, LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, ib.proddate, 121), 10),
    LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, ib.expdate, 121), 10), d.wmslocationid, d.wmspalletid,
    p.pallettypeid, xz.inputblockingcauseid, xz.outputblockingcauseid,
    d.inventserialid, d.inventownerid_via, d.inventlabelid_via, d.inventtaxstampid,
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.CaseQTY, 0) != 0 THEN bm.CaseQTY ELSE mm.CaseQTY END),
    k.standardPalletQuantity,
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.caseheight, 0) != 0 THEN bm.caseheight ELSE mm.caseheight END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casewidth, 0) != 0 THEN bm.casewidth ELSE mm.casewidth END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casedepth, 0) != 0 THEN bm.casedepth ELSE mm.casedepth END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casebarcode, '') != '' THEN bm.casebarcode ELSE mm.casebarcode END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.casebrutoweight, 0) != 0 THEN bm.casebrutoweight ELSE mm.casebrutoweight END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.alcopct, 0) != 0 THEN bm.alcopct ELSE mm.alcopct END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.blockqty, 0) != 0 THEN bm.blockqty ELSE mm.blockqty END),
    (CASE WHEN ISNULL(bm.exciseproductregnum, '') != ''
          THEN bm.exciseproductregnum
          ELSE mm.exciseproductregnum
     END),
    k.MMFItemProductGroupId;
```

> Error in SQL:Error in SQL:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: White space and line breaks woyuld make that SQL readable. Also, that statement isn't complete. A SQL statement can't start wuith `SUM`.

Comment: At first I wanted to point out which part is broken in my opinion, but okay I removed the mistake part

Comment: If the error says there's a division by zero, then you should try and check the values in the divisor are not zero. Maybe try removing the divisions one at a time to see which one fails

Comment: To narrow down the problem rows you could comment out the `laoseiskaste` and `vabakaste` columns (which will be the source of your errors) then add `and (bm.CaseQTY = 0 or mm.CaseQTY = 0)` to your where clause to see where those values are 0.

Comment: Side note -- use explicit joins everywhere.

Comment: Looks like this is the only division in the query: `SUM(CASE WHEN bm.CaseQTY IS NULL THEN (k.postedqty / mm.CaseQTY) ELSE (k.postedqty / bm.CaseQTY) END) AS laoseiskaste,` so I would recommend starting your debugging there.

Comment: The fact that you are telling the RDBMS what index to use, and the spattering of `NOLOCK` also suggests to me that you have some (major) performance and index choice problems. And by index choice, I mean the one's you've chosen to make, not the one's that SQL Server has chosen to use. It is a very rare event indeed that SQL Server will make the wrong choice on the index to use unless the statistics are awfully out of date. The fact you are forcing it in so many places suggests some big design or maintenance flaws.

Comment: The classic way to avoid division by zero without having to dive down the rabbit hole to find out how and why the zero happens is to replace `A / B` with `A / NULLIF(B, 0)` to produce a `NULL` rather than an error. (Unlike `CASE`, which can under circumstances evaluate expressions even if the conditions don't match, this will never error out.) You can then further use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` or an explicit test for `NULL` to do something else.

Comment: @Alex if that is the case then the OP would benefit significantly from spending some time on maintenance.

Comment: You can also troubleshoot by changing every `/ mm.CaseQTY` and `/ bm.CaseQTY` to `/ case when mm.CaseQTY = 0 then 0.000000001 else mm.CaseQTY` and `/ case when bm.CaseQTY = 0 then 0.000000001 else bm.CaseQTY`

Comment: The simple answer might be to change `where 1=1` *(side note that should be removed it that's the actual code)* to `where mm.CaseQTY <> 0 and bm.CaseQTY <> 0`

Comment: Regardless of all of this, the error is telling you that either mm.CaseQTY or bm.CaseQTY (or both) is zero.  You must decide what you want to do when one or the other is zero and then change the query accordingly.  It's not actually an error with your code -- it's just that the data you have doesn't work with the code you're trying to run -- if that makes any sense.

Comment: @SeanLange, and my comment was deleted because?

Comment: @Alex I did not delete your comment. They can only be deleted by the person who posted the comment or an admin. I am neither of those things.:) That being said I don't remember exactly what your comment said but it was nothing that deserved to be deleted imho.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, hit `Ctrl+F` to open the Find & Replace dialogue box. Search the query for all instances of `/`. This will tell you everywhere that division is happening, plus some false positives.

In every single instance, the query is dividing by `mm.CaseQTY` or `bm.CaseQTY`. Those are the only two values, and the only two tables you have to worry about. One or the other of them is coming through as a zero.

We don't have access to your database, so we can't help you troubleshoot the data issue, but that's how I'd go about deciding where to start looking.